# When you connect a type-c charger to a Lenovo laptop, in the area where the charger is connected, something starts to make sounds

Tags: laptop, lenovo-laptop, charger

When you connect a type-c charger to a Lenovo laptop, inside the case, in the area where the charger is connected, something starts to make sounds similar to grinding or a Geiger counter. Help, please, deal with this, I don’t want to disassemble, the laptop is new and expensive.

My laptop model: **ThinkBook 14 G2 ITL**

Comment: If it's new then it's under warranty. The first thing to do is to contact the tech/customer support and ask, not random people on the internet.

Comment: Almost certainly coil whine.

Comment: Many modern switch mode power supplies make noise due to [coil whine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_induced_acoustic_noise) as inductors vibrate due to a rapidly changing electromagnetic field. Your first job it to find out if this is normal for your laptop. If it is not or you cannot live with it then you may have to simply return it and get a different one.

Comment: Lenovo's official word on the matter: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/solutions/ht511649 TL;DR "We try to design it to be as quiet as possible, but it is a normal fact of how things work these days." Their exact words are **This is not a hardware defect. The product is operating within specification and within the acoustic tolerance for the level of sound emitted by the product during regular operation. No impact on the performance of the product exists.**

Comment: No issue here with a couple of X1 machines.  Return to Lenovo if the noise is too bad for you.

Comment: That is, as I understand you all correctly, the best option would be to take the laptop to the store to look at it and, if something does not suit me, change it.

I was still interested to know the opinion of people (not just consultants in the store) on this matter, and all of a sudden, to be ready for such similar things in the future, suddenly I can fix something myself. If I continue my question from now, please tell me, these sounds that I described in the topic, is this generally normal for a laptop?

Comment: is this generally normal for a laptop?   .... No, not for Lenovo laptops. I have used lots of these.

Comment: @JeR if the sound is only audible in a quiet room then they may consider it normal. If it is louder than someone speaking normally then it may be something that needs a professional to look at. We can't determine for you sadly, as microphones tend to amplify small noises and exaggerate this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the coil-whine examples that I heard, a whine was a whine, sometimes with
modulations, but not grinding or Geiger sounds.
So I'm not sure that the problem is truly a coil-whine.

My advice : Do not try to open the case, because this can void your warranty,
or give the vendor an excuse for rejecting you.

If you can't live with the noise, and it doesn't go away, replace or return
the laptop. Trying to fix a hardware problem in an all-new laptop under
warranty is just a waste of your money.

Comment: Coil whine today comes in all shapes and sizes - not just literal whine - so I wouldn't rule out what OP heard. For example, I've heard coil whine that sounded exactly like a mechanical HDD.

Comment: Interesting, but notwithstanding I would still advise against taking the risk of doing hardware manipulations on new hardware under warranty.

Comment: I have some power supplies that when the machine finishes charging they essentially go into an idle mode and seem to chirp (for want of a better word) at about 4 times per second. It is still a form of coil whine because the chirp is the coil being briefly energised to apply power at a much lower frequency to see if the other side is actually going to draw power. As you say though coil-whine is not something a user can change or fix, opening the machine is pointless unless you know the problem is something they can really fix.

Comment: While "coil-whine" has become embedded in the PC lexicon, a better term is just, "component noise." Unless you can see the coil, you probably can't identify if the noise is actually from a coil or not. Capactiors can make plenty of noise, and they're not really a coil.